# Find object from dom element on event

Tags: javascript, dom

I have created some instances of an object.  One function in the object creates a `li` element and uses `addEventListener("click", this, false)`.
when the Event Handler runs it can show the objects instance variables etc. so basically I know its accessing the proper instance of the object and running the event handler.

So there is a way to trace back from the dom element to the instance of the object that created it.  In this case the `this` is what is providing the link.

What I would like to do is get the element by selector or id.  Then somehow get the instance of the object.  Find out what the `this` for the element is (not referring to the dom element as `this`)  I am thinking a workaround would be to create a custom event and return the object itself in the handler function. Then get the element and run it like `myElement.click()`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: please add a [mcve] because it's hard to understand code when discussed in prose.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basic flavor, making use of `this`:

```
const obj = {
  name: "my object",
  listen() {
    someElement.addEventListener('click', this.listener.bind(this));
  };
  listener(event) {
    console.log("The event and this name are", event, this.name);
  }
};
```

You could also use the `handleEvent` approach:

```
const obj = {
  name: "my object",
  handleEvent() { console.log("I was clicked!", this.name); },
  listen() {
    someElement.addEventListener('click', this);
  }
};
```

Comment: indeed but I am needing to get the object instance from the context of another element.

Comment: I don't understand. What other element?

Comment: I would think it would work like this.  var el = document.getElementById('myElement') then find out what object instance created it. var mainObject = el.myObjectHandler() then i could call mainObject.name and get the same result as if it were clicked.

Comment: If you want to associate an object with a DOM element, then you can add the reference as a property on the DOM element when you create it, as in `el.creatingObject = object;`.

Comment: Figured I was missing something simple.  Thanks